# How can I add HTML Attributes on <Button>/<ButtonBase> in Material-UI?

Tags: button, attributes, material-ui

When using the Material-UI library, how can I add html attributes to `<Button>` and `<ButtonBase>`? For example be able to set tabindex to -1 on a button.

I see for components like `<TextField>` you can use InputProps, but there doesn't seem to be any props like that on `<Button>` and `<ButtonBase>`.

I created a feature request here ([issue 9585](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/9585)) but was told it is possible to do already.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says in the docs: "Any other properties supplied will be spread to the root element."

For `Button`, that's `ButtonBase`, and for `ButtonBase` it's `button` (by default, you can override with the `component` prop.). So: `tabIndex` supplied to `Button` will be applied to `ButtonBase`, which in turn will apply it to `button`.

In the case of `tabIndex`, you also have the `disabled` prop which sets `tabIndex={-1}`.

Comment: Thank you! It was 4 in the morning and I had tried "tabindex" instead of "tabIndex". It's good to know that properties will be spread to the root element.

Comment: No prob. It is confusing that lowercased HTML props are camelCased in React. If this solved your problem, please mark the answer correct to help others find it.